# TicTacToe Check Wins Error

Tags: python

```
def check_board():
     global y
    for a in howtowin:
        for b in range(num):
            y.append([board1[a[b]]])    
        if all(y == 'X'):
            print("\nPlayer 1 Wins!")
            print("Congratulations!\n")
            return True
        elif all(y == 'O'):
            print("\nPlayer 2 Wins!")
            print("Congratulations!\n")
            return True
    for a in range(num*num):
        if board1[a] == 'X' or board1[a] == 'O':
            count += 1
        if count == num*num:
            print("The game ends in a Tie\n")
            return True
```

I'm making a program and I've been trying to fix this method for a week. It needs to take in any side length and check with "howtowin" if there are any winning combinations. "howtowin" is a tuple of win combinations that works for any board side length. Currently the first line in the second loop errors with:

```
NameError: global name 'y' is not defined
```

Comment: Is `num` an integer? If so you need to do `for b in range(0, num)`.

Answer (score 0):

That first for loop appears to be your problem:

```
    for b in num:
        x.append([board1[a[b]]])
```

That should be :

```
    for b in range(num):
        x.append([board1[a[b]]])
```